# "Illegal invocation" error for call to member of newly-created Web components object

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

When I try to run the `clear` function in the following code snippet in Chrome, I get an `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation` error.

I'm creating a web component with some functions for a text input. This is my first method but I keep getting that error and I have no clue what it could be.

```
var XEditProto = Object.create(HTMLInputElement.prototype);

XEditProto.clear = function() {
    this.value = '';
    return "Erased";
}

var Edit = document.registerElement('x-edit', {
    prototype: XEditProto,
    extends: 'input'
});
document.body.appendChild(new Edit());
```

Comment: How do you call the `.clear()` function?

Comment: Please check the code again had some mistakes there, i call it XEditProto.clear()

Comment: `Object doesn't support property or method 'registerElement'` Does that help?

Comment: change `XEditProto.value = '';` to `this.value = '';`

Comment: and don't  `call it XEditProto.clear()` ... `var x = document.body.appendChild(new Edit());` ... `x.clear();`

Comment: @Jaromanda, sorry, i was testing changing it to XEditProto to see if it works, im getting the error when i use this.value = ' '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var XEditProto = Object.create(HTMLInputElement.prototype);

XEditProto.clear = function() {
    this.value = '';
    return "Erased";
}

var Edit = document.registerElement('x-edit', {
    prototype: XEditProto,
    extends: 'input'
});
var x = document.body.appendChild(new Edit());
```

...

```
x.clear();
```

Works as expected

Comment: Yes! that was it! thanks a lot!

Im REALLY new to Web components, Web Dev and coding in general so i got really lost with this. Thanks Again :)